# How to update arrya value in react Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

Here TotalRegistrationCard is functional componet where I am receiving dynamic props value ,
const{dasboardVal}=props;
after console of dasboardVal.data. I am getting one array of object and after mapping .
Please help thanks

```
const graphVal = () =>{
    if (!_.isEmpty(dasboardVal)){
      return dasboardVal.data.map((item, index) => (
          item.value.length
          ));
    }
  }

dasboardVal.data. geting value 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] its dynamic data
```

now I have one state const [data, setData] = useState()

whose current value is

```
{
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Now I have  to update the state [data, setData] = useState()
and the update value should be

```
{
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      },
    ],
  }
```

const TotalRegistrationCard = props => {
const{dasboardVal}=props;

```
 const graphVal = () =>{
    if (!_.isEmpty(dasboardVal)){
      return dasboardVal.data.map((item, index) => (
          item.value.length
          ));
    }
  }


  const [data, setData] = useState({
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [],
      },
    ],
  });
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `dasboardVal` and what do you want to achieve with  the graphVal function?

Comment: actually dasboardVal.data  this is array I am getting from props and then I am mapping it because it is coming as a object of array with other values .. after filtering I am getting [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]  this and I have to replace this to [320, 523, 548, 321, 490, 330, 380] because

Comment: Please submit more details for your question, not able to get it

Comment: Just updated my question , please suggest . Thanks for your reaponse

Comment: @BhavinParghi please suggest , I have updated the question

Comment: @Disco  Please help for this

Comment: @abhigyankr try editing your question. At the moment it's unclear

Comment: Is your question to just ask how to update the `dataset.data` value to a new value?

Comment: @ArunBohra  just updated actully  dataset.data is a array and after maping i am getting value in graphVal which  is [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] not this value I have to push to const [data, setData] = useState , here we can see some value datasets: [
      {
        data: [320, 523, 548, 321, 490, 330, 380],
      },
    ],
I have to replace [320, 523, 548, 321, 490, 330, 380] with  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where you able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The question does not actually make it clear, so I am assuming you need to update the part of the state

assuming you current state to be

```
{
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [320, 523, 548, 321, 490, 330, 380],
      },
    ],
 }
```

and it needs to be updated to

```
{
    labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'],
    datasets: [
      {
        data: [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      },
    ],
  }
```

you should be able to do

```
 useEffect(() => {
 
    if (!_.isEmpty(dasboardVal)){
      const updatedDatasets =  dasboardVal?.data?.map((item, index) => (
      item.value.length
      ));
      setData(d => ({ ...d, datasets: [ { data: updatedDatasets } })
    } else {
       // updates when no data or just dont show a different component
       // setData(d => ({ ...d, datasets: updatedDatasets })
     }

 }, [dasboardVal]) // should be able to use dashboardVal?.data also
```

still I dont understand how you can update the datasets array without a key

and you might want to use [immer](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#write-concise-update-logic-with-immer) to make things easier

and you might want to read the new React documentation of [state updates](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state)

hope it helps

Comment: please allow me 2 minutes upadating it

Comment: just updated the questionn

Comment: I encourage you to go through the new React documentations, it will really help https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/adding-interactivity